# Redirecting to email user site

Tags: php, email, redirect

I tried execute this code and I have done something wrong because it's always redirecting me to google:

```
    <?php

$email = $_POST['email'];
$after_email = explode('@', $email);
$part = $part[1];
if($part == 'aol.com') {
        header("Location: http://aol.com");
} else if($part == 'yahoo.com') {
        header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
} else {
        header("Location: http://google.com");
}
?>
```

this is my html form

```
<form action="snd.php">
email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You do not provide enough information to troubleshoot this. What is the value of `$_POST['email']`?

Comment: example@aol.com
and it still redirect me to google.com

Comment: Because you are checking the wrong variable. `$part` doesn't exist. You should be using `$after_email[1]`. You should be developing with error reporting on and simple mistakes like this one would become super obvious to you. Voting to close ad a simple typo.

Comment: Change the line `$part = $part[1];` to `$part = $after_email[1];`. I think if you had done something like `var_dump($part)` right after you defined it you would have seen that there was a problem. Dumping your variables and verifying you are getting what you expect is a critical part of debugging.

Comment: i just met php and im still learning it

Comment: @GiSlayer no one is saying you are not new, what we are saying is reread your code. Where is `$part[1]` defined in your code? It seems like a case of copying a snippet when you must have learnt to split emails and then you forgot that you renamed the variable to `$after_email`.

Comment: i changed it but its still redirects to the else condition

Comment: Dump (`var_dump`) `$part`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You called the `explode()` function on `$email`. This implies that `$after_email` is now an array. Your mistake was that you were accessing the wrong array variable.

Change this line:

```
$part = $part[1];
```

to:

```
$part = $after_email[1];
```

**EDIT**

Change this line in your form too:

```
<form action="snd.php">
```

to:

```
<form action="snd.php" method="post">
```

You also didn't specify the form method. By default, this is set to `$_GET`. But in your php script, you were calling the `$_POST` superglobal. Change the method to `post` and you are good to go.

Comment: Still same problem

Comment: Keeps redirecting to Google?

Comment: yes
i have put example@yahoo.com
and example@aol.com
in the form
but still reidrects to google

Comment: Dump (`var_dump`) `$part`.

Comment: its working i will look t it a agin because i didnt understand what was the problem

Comment: I left some comments in my solution. You can start from there.